# How to Fill Height with middle Column in Kotlin Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have 3 Columns in a parent Column:

```
Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            MenuHeader()

            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight().background(color = Color.Blue)
            ) {
                Text("Middle Section with remaining height")
            }

            MenuTabBar()
        }
    }
```

And I want the middle column to be the full middle height, between the MenuHeader() and the MenuTabBar().

I've tried to set the Arrangement to `.Top`, and `.SpaceBetween`, but neither work?

When I do `.Top`, the bottom bar disappears, I'm assuming the middle column is pushing it out of view because of the `.fillMaxHeight`.

Both `MenuHeader` and `MenuTabBar` have the following modifier:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
) {
```

Am I supposed to modify the children in this case, or the parent column?

Comment: You should consider using Scafold:
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#scaffold

Answer (score 1):

I just had to add `.weight(1f)` to middle Column modifier